# Is PEAK ("python enterprise application kit") still relevant?

Tags: python, python-packaging

I'm trying to 'learn me some python packaging,' but keep getting bogged down in all the different ways of doing things. So far I have encountered setuptools, easy-install, requirements.txt, setup.py, poetry, and just now I found out about something called PEAK ("python enterprise application kit"). Regarding the latter: is this even still relevant? The website appears to be from about 2004. Looks comprehensive, but I don't want to invest a bunch of time assimilating a methodology that is outdated.

P.S. I do not care about Python 2.X, as I am only using Python 3.7+. So that might be another factor.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.  Check the guidelines on opinion-based questions.

Comment: Have you read the [**Python Packaging User Guide**](https://packaging.python.org/)? Also, Questions "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more" are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never heard of it. Found this site http://peak.telecommunity.com/ where it appears after 13 years of silence. Package PEAK on PyPI was not updated since 2004. Last realse looks to be made By Phillip J. Eby Thursday, 01 May, 2003  And
this at the end of release note

> You can also find current and in-development source code at Github.

links to https://github.com/PEAK-Legacy/. So I would to assume it's dead except maybe some inner developmnet at some corporation

Comment: That was my initial conclusion as well, but thought someone on SO might know otherwise. Thanks for taking the time to respond.